# Modifiy a primeNG Chart

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I need to modify the pie chart from PrimeNg https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/chart/pie library to make a gauge instead, (just a semi-circle), is there someone who know how to do it? See bellow my code, I tried to change the option "circumference" but it doesn't do what I expect:

Here's my app.html:

```
 <div class="chart1">

 <p-chart type="pie" [data]="data" [options]="options"></p-chart>

 </div>
```

Here's my app.ts:

```
   this.data = {
        labels: ['Indispo', 'Dispo'],
        datasets: [
            {
                data: [300, 50, 100],
                backgroundColor: [
                    '#fffeff',
                    '#648e59'
                ],
                hoverBackgroundColor: [
                    '#fffeff',
                    '#648e59'
                ]
            }]
        };

        this.options = {
          title: {
            display: true,
            circumference: 50 * Math.PI,
            text: 'Informations sur le fonctionnement',
            fontSize: 20
          },
        legend: {
          position: 'right'
        }
        };
```

Comment: does primseNG has support for guage chart ? i donot think so as it is not mentioned on their webpage . you may need to change the lib you are using try high charts instead

Comment: @RahulSingh thanks you confirm me what I was thinking..so I'll move to a different library..I think I'll choose ngx-Charts link there: chartshttps://github.com/swimlane/ngx-charts